# Type parameter lifetime moved to async closure

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

How can I make the following snippet to compile without changing trait bounds as compile error suggests? The compiler suggests

`impl<M: Serialize + DeserializeOwned + 'static> WebSocketExchanger<M>`

but I really don't want to add `'static` bound.
That problematic part is the closure in `sink.with` function. What is the proper solution here?

```rust
use futures_util::{Sink, SinkExt, Stream, StreamExt, TryFutureExt, TryStreamExt};
use serde::de::DeserializeOwned;
use serde::Serialize;
use std::error::Error;
use std::pin::Pin;
use std::sync::Arc;
use tokio_tungstenite::connect_async;
use tokio_tungstenite::tungstenite::client::IntoClientRequest;
use tokio_tungstenite::tungstenite::Message;

pub trait Exchanger<M: Serialize + DeserializeOwned> {
    fn receiver(&mut self) -> &mut Pin<Box<dyn Stream<Item = anyhow::Result<M>>>>;
    fn sender(&mut self) -> &mut Pin<Box<dyn Sink<M, Error = anyhow::Error>>>;
}

pub struct WebSocketExchanger<M: Serialize + DeserializeOwned> {
    stream: Pin<Box<dyn Stream<Item = anyhow::Result<M>>>>,
    sink: Pin<Box<dyn Sink<M, Error = anyhow::Error>>>,
}

impl<M: Serialize + DeserializeOwned> Exchanger<M> for WebSocketExchanger<M> {
    fn receiver(&mut self) -> &mut Pin<Box<dyn Stream<Item = anyhow::Result<M>>>> {
        &mut self.stream
    }

    fn sender(&mut self) -> &mut Pin<Box<dyn Sink<M, Error = anyhow::Error>>> {
        &mut self.sink
    }
}

impl<M: Serialize + DeserializeOwned> WebSocketExchanger<M> {
    pub async fn connect<R: IntoClientRequest + Unpin>(request: R) -> anyhow::Result<Self> {
        let (web_socket, _) = connect_async(request).await?;
        let (web_socket_sink, web_socket_stream) = web_socket.split();

        let sink = web_socket_sink.with(move |x: M| async move {
            serde_json::to_string(&x)
                .map_err(anyhow::Error::from)
                .map(|s| Message::text(s))
        });

        let stream = web_socket_stream
            .map(|m| match m {
                Ok(message) => anyhow::Ok(message),
                Err(err) => Err(anyhow::Error::from(err)),
            })
            .map(|m| match m {
                Ok(msg) => anyhow::Ok(serde_json::from_str::<M>(msg.to_text()?)?),
                Err(err) => Err(err),
            });

        anyhow::Ok(Self {
            stream: Box::pin(stream),
            sink: Box::pin(sink),
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're already constraining on `DeserializeOwned`, that will effectively require `M` has no non-static references anyway so what's the issue with `+ 'static`?

Comment: Perhaps you are confused about what `'static` means as a constraint? There's some good info from [Common Rust Lifetime Misconceptions](https://github.com/pretzelhammer/rust-blog/blob/master/posts/common-rust-lifetime-misconceptions.md#2-if-t-static-then-t-must-be-valid-for-the-entire-program) by pretzelhammer.

Comment: @kmdreko originally I had just `Deserialize`. I changed it to owned in hope to fix it. The doc https://serde.rs/lifetimes.html says I should not do `'static`. Do you know how to fix it if I revert to `Deserialize`?

Comment: The link says `Deserialize<'static>` and `Deserialize<'_> + 'static` are wrong, but that does not extend to `DeserializeOwned + 'static`. You should read that entire article to understand what the lifetime in `Deserialize` means and the implications therein. You can't make `Deserialize<'_>` work in your code. You want `DeserializeOwned` because you don't want your `M` to be bound to the life of the source data (since you immediately throw it away after deserialization).